# Turn off speaker & screen from shell

Tags: shell, audio

Is it possible to disable speakers , screen display, touch screen from shell command ?

I am trying to achieve silence in android using the shell capabilities (with root).
I can also remove files.

Meanwhile I've tried several options, yet nothing results in silence.

EDIT:
I have found the list of devices with

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
                                              <
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="pmic8xxx_pwrkey"
P: Phys=pmic8xxx_pwrkey/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/msm_ssbi.0/pm8921-core/pm8xxx-pwrkey/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 keychord cpufreq
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0001
N: Name="keypad_8064"
P: Phys=keypad_8064/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/msm_ssbi.0/pm8921-core/pm8xxx-keypad/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 keychord cpufreq
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=c0000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="touch_dev"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 cpufreq
B: PROP=2
B: EV=9
B: ABS=6618000 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="apq8064-tabla-snd-card Button Jack"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc-audio.0/sound/card0/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event3 cpufreq
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=ff 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="apq8064-tabla-snd-card Headset Jack"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc-audio.0/sound/card0/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 cpufreq
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1c054

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0001
N: Name="hs_detect"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 cpufreq
B: PROP=0
B: EV=23
B: KEY=4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
B: SW=14
```

Now I tried for example to change some attribute in touch screen, but seems I can't control it.

```
root@mako:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input2 # ls
capabilities
event2
id
modalias
name
phys
power
properties
subsystem
uevent
uniq
```

I haven't tried all attributes yet. Maybe I missed something?

**EDIT:
On trying to set brightness directly to device, I see effect, but for some reason 0 does not correspond to turning off display, it only results in darker screen.**
I also tried to remove gui libraries such as libgui, libsurfaceflinger, bit then android boot is not finished.

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/msm_fb.525825/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
echo 0 > /sys/devices/i2c-0/0-0038/backlight/lm3530/brightness
```

I am trying to do that from low level, because I can't achieve the same from android. I think it is very important on this forum, and there might be other interested too.

Comment: I've edit the question

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026171/how-to-set-brightness-through-adb-on-nexus-7 http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/how-can-i-remotely-change-the-volume http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391326/how-to-change-the-volume-using-adb-shell-service-call-audio ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Android. Although Android uses a Linux kernel, it is not a Unix system. You can ask Android usage questions on [android.se] and Android programming questions on [so].

Comment: I am trying to do that from low level, because I can't achieve the same from android. I think it is very important on this forum, and there might be other interested too. I edited the question now.